# Complex number as the result of an integral

Tags: numerical-integration, complex

My question has been asked before by other members, however, I didn't find the answer to their question helpful in my case.
I'm doing a simple numerical integral with real numbers in mathematica, but I get a complex number as a result. This is my integral:

```
NIntegrate[f1[x], {x, b1, b2}]
```

, where

```
f1[x_] := 0.0472245 (4.2312 - x)^3.53272 (-1.19737 + x)^0.630549;
```

and `b1 = 4.2312` and `b2 = 8.46239`.

The result is 2.40249 - 23.2898i. This is a complex number which I don't expect. Does someone know why I get this result? and, is there any way to avoid getting it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The expression `(4.2312 - x)^3.53272` is complex when `x > 4.2312`.  As to how to avoid it: Well, it's correct for the function you've written. If you think the answer should be real, then you set up the function or interval wrong.  Maybe you want `(x - 4.2312)^3.53272`

Comment: If `a` and `b` are real numbers and `a > 0`, then `(-a)^b` is equivalent to `Exp[b (I \[Pi] + Log[a])]`, in case you're wondering why it should be complex.

Answer (score 4):

When plotting the real and imaginary part of your function

```
Plot[
  Evaluate@ReIm[f1[x]], {x, 1, 5},
  PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Re[f[x]]", "Im[f[x]]"}, 
  GridLines -> {List @@ Reduce[f1[x] == 0, x, Reals][[All, 2]], None}
]
```

[image: Plot of real and imaginary part of f1[x].]

you can see, that only in the range $1.19737 < x < 4.2312$ the function evaluates to purely real values. Like Michael already commented, a fractional power of a negative value will produce complex values outside of that range. Hope that helps to understand the result you got!